# Handling 7K Size Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a list of every college in America. As you can imagine it is a pretty massive list.. 7,000 rows.

I am not too experienced with Javascript but I can't imagine loading an array that size would be good for performance.. All I really want the user to be able to do is start typing their college and autocomplete finishing it. That Way I can assure that there is no error in the system.

Has anyone ever done something like this before? is there a good way to handle this? Json?

Comment: Agreed. Have the JSON stored in Server, and ask JS to send a request after each Character. Limit for 20 rows.

Comment: Large data, if handled correctly, should not be a huge problem if there's enough RAM. The problem with JS, HTML and large data sets is that if you try adding 7000 divs to the DOM it'll crash the browser. So keep them in memory and limit the number of displayed rows to a minimum. If you need to display a lot then try a _virtualized list_.

Comment: Rather that sending request on each character, you can wait till user pauses for say 1 sec and then fire.